# How to disable transaction logs in recovery mode simple?

Tags: sql-server

I need to transfer lots of data between two tables in different databases, such as:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MoveThenTruncateMyData]
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyDB2_TEST.dbo.MyData (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
        SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 
        FROM MyDB1_TEST.dbo.MyData;

    TRUNCATE TABLE MyDB1_TEST.dbo.MyData;
END
```

I set MyDB2_TEST in recovery mode simple.

However, once the rows start to move, the log file size starts to increase.

Since the database data file is 80 gb, it seems logs will be 3x times bigger while the transaction is running.

The problem is that I don't have enough space on that machine: it will saturate.

Is there any way to disable also transaction logs? In this case, if the operation fails, I can just re-do it.

Comment: No, you can't disable transaction logs; they are still required even when using the simple recovery model. Perhaps you would be better off `INSERT` the data in batches, so that the transaction log grows for that batch, and then once you `COMMIT` it, then the transaction log can can be truncated (this is a over simplification of how logs work).

Comment: Another option worth considering is trying to leverage minimal logging. This is worthwhile even in simple recovery, since it minimizes how much log is needed in the first place. There are several requirements and restrictions on when an operation can be minimally logged, so it's not always possible, but when it is it helps. For a cross-database operation like this, pure T-SQL can't help (I think), but a client ETL process that bulk inserts could.

Comment: @AaronBertrand MyTable2_TEST is another DB (typo on write the question; i've edited it now)

Comment: A couple of articles that might be useful: [Break large delete operations into chunks](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) (equally applicable to inserts/updates) and [Refreshing Tables With Less Interruption Using Partition Switching](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/sql-performance/refreshing-tables-partition-switching).

Comment: You cans use a regular CHECKPOINT / BACKUP LOG MyDatabase TO DISK = 'NUL'; This will empty the transaction log file as frequently you do so

Comment: @SQLpro this won't have any effect on a single insert statement that inserts 1 billion rows. You have to combine that with breaking up the insert into smaller pieces.

Comment: @arron_bertrand Yes like with an INSERT TOP (n)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable transaction logs in any recovery model. The reason is that you have to be able to roll back any transaction in whole; the log has to contain everything required to perform that rollback. So if you have a single insert that jams 1 billion rows into a table, the log for that database has to keep all that info around until the transaction commits. Ways you can offset that:

- [break the operation into chunks](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes)
- use [minimal logging](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/sql-server-2016-minimal-logging-and-impact-of-the-batchsize-in/ba-p/385537)
- [move the data differently](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/sql-performance/refreshing-tables-partition-switching) (in combo with chunking)
- don't move the data at all (e.g. couldn't one database just have a view that points to the other database?)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to perform a bulk operation it's recommended to set recovery model to Bulked-log not simple. With Bulked-log recovery model the logs will be written at minimal mode.

Another point is to divide your insert in several batches; Because the logs won't be truncated until the transaction commits.

Comment: @Meyssam_Toluie No it is not recommended at all. But yes you can, except if your database is involved in an AlwaysOn availability group, or a mirroring replicia or a log shipping...

Comment: @SQLpro Yes those are exceptions. In those cases we can suspend Data Flow to speed up the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of how you're trying to do the data movement (i.e. all-or-nothing), I present an alternative:

```
delete top(1000)
from MyDB1_TEST.dbo.MyData
output deleted.Column1, deleted.Column2, deleted.Column3, deleted.Column4
into MyDB2_TEST.dbo.MyData(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4);
```

I chose 1000 rows arbitrarily; pick a number that works for you. Either way, this lets you move a small number of rows at a time in a transactionally consistent manner. You will have to make sure that your application is aware of the state of things during the transition (maybe a view that spans both tables?) but this lets you keep the transaction log impact to one batch's worth.